# Solving $\displaystyle \int_{-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}^{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}\log(2\cos \theta)d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}^{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}\int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{2\cos\theta}\frac{1}{x}dxd\theta=\int_{-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}^{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}(\log(2\cos \theta)\,\mathrm +\log(a))d\theta=$$
$$=2\log(a)(\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1})+\int_{-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}^{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1}}\log(2\cos \theta)d\theta$$

I want to to know if when $a\rightarrow \infty$ the original integral converges and I don't know how to solve the last integral and it seems its difficult (maybe its necesary use further techniques).

So maybe a better way its use inequalites   and find an easier integral but I cant find it, so can you help me  please?

Comment: Use integration by parts.

Comment: Integration by parts leaves you with $\int xtanx \,dx$

Comment: Do you need the antiderivative or the evaluation of a definite integral (say from 0 to $\pi$)?

Comment: Can you help me or give me some hint please?

Comment: Please write down the source of the problem and what techniques you've learned so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for $a\to \infty$, $\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2a^2-1} \to \frac\pi2$. Then, the Integral

$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\log(2\cos \theta)d\theta=0$$

However, the first term $2\log(a)(\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4a^2-1})$
diverges; so does the original integral.

————-

Edit:

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(2\cos x)dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(2\sin x)dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(2\cos\frac{x}{2})dx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(2\sin\frac{x}{2})dx\\
&=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(2\cos x)dx+2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(2\sin x)dx\\
&=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(2\cos x)dx+2\int^{\frac\pi2}_{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(2\cos x)dx\\
&=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(2\cos x)dx=2I \implies I=0
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks but how do you know $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\log(2\cos\theta)d\theta=0$

Comment: @JhonKnows please see the edit

Comment: Thank you so much